# How do I access the filtered size of the grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I'm using the ng grid. And I'm using the filter. I've got that much functioning properly. Now I would like to know (programmatically) how many items remain in the grid.

I've dug into the source on github, and found that the value is stored as:

```
grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache.length;
```

But I haven't been able to figure out how to access that variable, specifically the `grid` object from JS outside of the grid itself.

Other SO answers have included code like this:

```
angular.element($("#gridDiv")).scope()
```

And while that code works, it accesses the scope (which I already have access to in the JS), not the data used inside the grid. Is there a way to access the javascript objects inside the grid?

[Sample Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8SBGHBh3SCzZ6Ldh0Vtv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking around in `gridOptions` I've found an object with the name `filteredRows`.
So you can get the length you're looking for like this:

`$scope.gridOptions.ngGrid.filteredRows.length`

Please have a look at the demo below or here in the updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/QCSJV4kEyVHpuObEgSrb?p=preview).

(The `onRegisterApi` was just a test and it's not needed.)

```js
// main.js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
                     
    $scope.filter = {filterText:''};
    $scope.gridOptions = {
      data: 'myData',
      enableFiltering: true,
    filterOptions: $scope.filter,
    showFilter: true,
    onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) {
          $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
          $scope.gridApi.core.on.filterChanged( $scope, function() {
            console.log($scope.gridApi);
          });
    }
  };
  
  $scope.showRowCount = function() {
    console.log($scope.gridOptions.ngGrid.filteredRows.length);
  }
});
```

```css
.gridStyle {
    border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
    width: 400px; 
    height: 300px
}
```

```html
<link href="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/css/ng-grid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <input ng-model="filter.filterText"/>
      <button ng-click="showRowCount()">How many rows have been filtered</button>
        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
        currently visible items: {{gridOptions.ngGrid.filteredRows.length}}
    </div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for all of that. A+ for effort. What I needed (that you helpfully provided) was "Did you know that `ngGrid` is a property on the `gridOptions` object?"